# Failing loading js files

Tags: php, joomla, civicrm

I'm using Joomla mainly because I'm trying CiviCRM. Joomla is quite easy to install and it runs well on my server.

I've installed CiviCRM, which works well on local server, but CiviCRM app doesn't work well from outside the local server.

I can see that Firefox doesn't load correctly some js files, the location indicates my internal server address instead of the alias.

How do I solve this?

[image: Files not loaded]

Comment: Why do you think js files are not loaded? What I see is that Firefox has already cached those files.

Comment: You are right, files were loaded, this screen captures doesn't show the files that weren't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by manually updating the civicrm.settings and changing some values that were pointing localhost instead of my server URL.